# Managing FreeBSD host with Ansible fails: Shared object \"libdl.so.1\" not found, required by \"python\"\r\n

Tags: python, freebsd, ansible

Management of FreeBSD on Raspberry pi 3 (FreeBSD-aarch64-12.0-GENERIC-320146M from RaspBSD project - http://www.raspbsd.org/) fails.

Control host is MacOS 10.13.2.

python is successfully installed on the managed host (**rpi3_freebsd**):

```
$ ansible -m raw -a "sudo pkg install -y python27" --user drew --ask-pass rpi3_freebsd
SSH password:
rpi | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
Updating FreeBSD repository catalogue...
FreeBSD repository is up to date.
All repositories are up to date.
Checking integrity... done (0 conflicting)
The most recent version of packages are already installed
```

However, when I try to run a playbook, ansible returns the following error:

```
$ ansible-playbook --user drew --ask-pass bootstrap.yml -vvvv
ansible-playbook 2.4.3.0
  config file = /Users/drew/SynologyDrive/rpi-scripts/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/Users/drew/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/Cellar/ansible/2.4.3.0/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 2.7.10 (default, Jul 15 2017, 17:16:57) [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.31)]
Using /Users/drew/SynologyDrive/rpi-scripts/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
SSH password:
setting up inventory plugins
Parsed /Users/drew/SynologyDrive/rpi-scripts/ansible/hosts inventory source with ini plugin
Loading callback plugin skippy of type stdout, v2.0 from /usr/local/Cellar/ansible/2.4.3.0/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/skippy.pyc

PLAYBOOK: bootstrap.yml ******************************************************************************************************************
 1 plays in bootstrap.yml

PLAY [raspberrypi_3] *********************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *******************************************************************************************************************
Using module file /usr/local/Cellar/ansible/2.4.3.0/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/system/setup.py
<172.16.42.6> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: drew on PORT 22 TO 172.16.42.6
<172.16.42.6> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~ && sleep 0'
<172.16.42.6> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /home/drew/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1522353818.07-1230475463058 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1522353818.07-1230475463058="` echo /home/drew/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1522353818.07-1230475463058 `" ) && sleep 0'
<172.16.42.6> PUT /var/folders/2c/m_z3y5gs3fz1m2b2lwzk7yl80000gn/T/tmpgWCvx_ TO /home/drew/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1522353818.07-1230475463058/setup.py
<172.16.42.6> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /home/drew/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1522353818.07-1230475463058/ /home/drew/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1522353818.07-1230475463058/setup.py && sleep 0'
<172.16.42.6> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/local/bin/python /home/drew/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1522353818.07-1230475463058/setup.py; rm -rf "/home/drew/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1522353818.07-1230475463058/" > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
fatal: [rpi]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "module_stderr": "",
    "module_stdout": "Shared object \"libdl.so.1\" not found, required by \"python\"\r\n",
"msg": "MODULE FAILURE",
"rc": 0
}
to retry, use: --limit @/Users/drew/SynologyDrive/rpi-scripts/ansible/bootstrap.retry

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************************
rpi                        : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

The only dependency for ansible is python which is satisfied.

What is wrong and how can I fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: Does running just `python` work?

Comment: @arrowd, gotcha... returns this: `Shared object "libdl.so.1" not found, required by "python"`

Comment: Well, your python is broken somehow. Try reinstalling via ports or packages.

Comment: I am new to FreeBSD. I have installed it with `sudo pkg install python`. There was no errors. How would you suggest to reinstall it?

Answer (score 5):

Similar issue with missing dependency in bash and wget got fixed by creating a link

```
ln -sf /lib/libc.so.7 /usr/lib/libdl.so.1
```

Comment: After much searching, this did the trick in about a second.  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem happen when transitioning from FreeBSD 11.1 to 11.2, but it was `gnutls` that reported the problem with missing `libdl.so.1`.

My solution arose from a tip I found at:

https://forums.freenas.org/index.php?threads/openvpn-fails-in-jail-with-libdl-so-1-not-found-error.70391/#post-486449

First make a backup of `/etc/pkg/FreeBSD.conf`:

```
# cp -vp /etc/pkg/FreeBSD.conf /etc/pkg/FreeBSD.conf.safety
```

Then edit `/etc/pkg/FreeBSD.conf` and change the `url:` line to be:

```
url: "pkg+http://pkg.FreeBSD.org/${ABI}/release_2",
```

Save the file and exit vi.

```
# pkg update
# pkg install -f python27
```

Now try your ansible playbook again.

If that works, for you, and if you've upgraded other ports recently, you may want to give them a cursory invocation to ensure they don't have similar problems.

I am not an expert, but I would expect that this problem will go away once you get your OS up to a more recent version.  In my case, I believe the problem came about because the pkg repo was supplying packages linked for 11.2, which has a libdl.so.1, and I was installing them into a jail that was still at version 11.1, which does not.

Once you've upgraded to an up-to-date release, you should revert your `/etc/pkg/FreeBSD.conf` to the backup copy you made, and resume tracking the latest pkg repo.